# Lookup data from a source table by filtering on rows where columns match an input table or are blank

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I have a source lookup table like so (this is just an example for the purposes of this question):

```
| one   | two   | three | value |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
| FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | a     |
| FALSE | FALSE |  TRUE | b     |
| FALSE |       | FALSE | c     |
|  TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | e     |
|  TRUE | FALSE |  TRUE | f     |
|  TRUE |  TRUE |       | g     |
```

Notice how some cells are empty.

Then I have some input values like so:

```
| one   | TRUE  |
| two   | TRUE  |
| three | FALSE |
```

I am trying to use `FILTER` to find the associated `value` for the values in my `input`.

If my source table didn't have any empty cells then I could do something like this:

```
=FILTER(D:D, A:A = F2, B:B = F3, C:C = F4)
```

But this will not work because my source table has some empty cells.

I thought to use `OR` like so:

```
=FILTER(D:D, OR(A:A = "", A:A = F2), B:B = F3, C:C = F4)
```

But that does not work; it returns the error:

> FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 999. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.

I know I can use `QUERY` with a complex `WHERE` clause combining `and` and `or` but I am wondering if it is possible to do what I am after using `FILTER` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we use `AND()` , `OR()` it won't work with array, I'm not sure why

But we can count `true/false` as a number of `1 = true` and `0 = false`

So your formula would be

```
=FILTER(D:D, A:A = "" + A:A = F2 > 0, B:B = F3, C:C = F4)
```

use `> 0` instead of `OR()`

[image: result]

Comment: This works but I'm seeing something strange. If I use `=FILTER(D:D, A:A = "" + A:A = F2 > 0)`, it returns all rows even though that condition is not true for all of them. Do you know why?

Comment: If I understand correctly. It should work, anyways I'll show the result. Please tell me is it as your expect result?

Comment: Thanks. I think I made a mistake on my end. This seems to be working.

Answer (score 2):

if empty cells are considered as `FALSE` then:

```
=FILTER(D:D, A:A*1 = F2*1, B:B*1 = F3*1, C:C*1 = F4*1)
```

[image]

---

if empty cells are considered as `TRUE` then:

```
=FILTER(D:D, IF(A:A="", 1, A:A)*1 = F2*1, 
             IF(B:B="", 1, B:B)*1 = F3*1, 
             IF(C:C="", 1, C:C)*1 = F4*1)
```

[image: 0]

---

if empty cells are in quantum superposition use:

```
=FILTER(D:D, REGEXMATCH(A:A&"", F2&"|^$"), 
             REGEXMATCH(B:B&"", F3&"|^$"), 
             REGEXMATCH(C:C&"", F4&"|^$"), D:D<>"")
```

[image: 0]